# Logstash XML Parse Failed

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm running latest ELK stack 6.6 on deviantony/docker-elk image. I have the following XML file which I try to parse into ES JSON object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <ChainId>7290027600007</ChainId>
    <SubChainId>001</SubChainId>
    <StoreId>001</StoreId>
    <BikoretNo>9</BikoretNo>
    <DllVerNo>8.0.1.3</DllVerNo>
</root>
```

My conf file is:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/usr/share/logstash/logs/example1.xml"
    type => "xml"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "<?xml version"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}

filter {
    xml {
        source => "message"
        store_xml => false
        xpath => [ "/root/ChainId/text()", "ChainId" ]
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    index => "xml_index"
    manage_template => false
  }
}
```

My Logstash output is:

```
{
logstash_1       |     "@timestamp" => 2019-03-26T06:45:27.941Z,
logstash_1       |           "tags" => [
logstash_1       |         [0] "multiline"
logstash_1       |     ],
logstash_1       |           "host" => "751b3a8bf341",
logstash_1       |        "ChainId" => [],
logstash_1       |        "message" => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<root>\r\n    <ChainId>7290027600007</ChainId>\r\n    <SubChainId>001</SubChainId>\r\n    <StoreId>001</StoreId>\r\n    <BikoretNo>9</BikoretNo>\r\n    <DllVerNo>8.0.1.3</DllVerNo>\r\n</root>\r",
logstash_1       |           "path" => "/usr/share/logstash/logs/example1.xml",
logstash_1       |       "@version" => "1",
logstash_1       |           "type" => "xml"
logstash_1       | }
```

XML body under message is showing as a string with escaping and `\r\n`. XPath`ChainId` field returns empty array. I tried with other XML files as well with same results.

**Update**:
After trying to remove `\r\n` still not getting XPath parsed fields. My output is:

```
logstash_1       |        "message" => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root>    <ChainId>7290027600007</ChainId>    <SubChainId>001</SubChainId>    <StoreId>001</StoreId>    <BikoretNo>9</BikoretNo>    <DllVerNo>8.0.1.3</DllVerNo>",
logstash_1       |        "StoreId" => [],
logstash_1       |      "BikoretNo" => [],
logstash_1       |        "ChainId" => [],
logstash_1       |           "type" => "xml",
logstash_1       |           "tags" => [
logstash_1       |         [0] "multiline"
logstash_1       |     ],
logstash_1       |     "@timestamp" => 2019-03-27T20:51:09.575Z,
logstash_1       |       "DllVerNo" => [],
logstash_1       |           "path" => "/usr/share/logstash/logs/example1.xml",
logstash_1       |           "host" => "751b3a8bf341",
logstash_1       |     "SubChainId" => [],
logstash_1       |       "@version" => "1"
logstash_1       | }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `gsub` mutate filter to remove special character from message.

```
mutate { 
        gsub => [ "message", "[\r\n]", "" ] 
    }
```

Add target setting to xml filter for placing the data.

```
filter {

    xml{
        source => "message"
        store_xml => false
        target => "root"

    }

}
```

Here is the complete working logstash conf file.

```
input
{
    file
        {
            path => "C:\Users\KZAPAGOL\Desktop\CSV\XMLFile.xml"
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
            exclude => "*.gz"
            type => "xml"
            codec => multiline {
                    pattern => "<?xml " 
                    negate => "true"
                    what => "previous"
                }
        }
}

filter {

    xml{
        source => "message"
        store_xml => false
        target => "root"
        xpath => [
            "/root/ChainId/text()", "ChainId",
            "/root/SubChainId/text()", "SubChainId",
            "/root/StoreId/text()", "StoreId",
            "/root/BikoretNo/text()", "BikoretNo",
            "/root/DllVerNo/text()", "DllVerNo"
        ]
    }

    mutate { 
        gsub => [ "message", "[\r\n]", "" ] 
    }
}

output{

elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200/"]
        index => "parse_xml"
    }

    stdout
    {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "_index": "parse_xml",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "vNj4v2kBZ2Q_C9FO94eF",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2019-03-27T16:25:58.379Z",
    "path": "filePath",
    "tags": [
      "multiline"
    ],
    "ChainId": [
      "7290027600007"
    ],
    "BikoretNo": [
      "9"
    ],
    "DllVerNo": [
      "8.0.1.3"
    ],
    "host": "xxxx",
    "@version": "1",
    "SubChainId": [
      "001"
    ],
    "message": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root>    <ChainId>7290027600007</ChainId>    <SubChainId>001</SubChainId>    <StoreId>001</StoreId>    <BikoretNo>9</BikoretNo>    <DllVerNo>8.0.1.3</DllVerNo></root>",
    "type": "xml",
    "StoreId": [
      "001"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-03-27T16:25:58.379Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1553703958379
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: @wizard Please let me if it didn't work for you. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately no. Please check my updated log output. P.S. I saw you had tried this conf on windows machine. I'm running it on linux (both docker and my pc).

Comment: Can you please try this `/root/ChainId[text()]`.

Comment: No. XPath is not taking into effect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried you configuration and it works in windows environment, It hapends with me one time and I changed the xpath expression

Try to change the xpath expression to one of below

```
xpath => [ "//*[local-name() = 'ChainId']/text()", "ChainId" ]
```

OR

```
xpath => [ "//ChainId/text()", "ChainId" ]
```

Comment: @wizard try to add `remove_namespaces => "true"` to xml filter and change `sincedb_path => "NUL"`

Comment: I don't see any change.

Comment: @wizard do you stop and start logstash after config update?

Comment: yes. of course. I set `--config.reload.automatic` and I also tried to stop and restart.

Comment: alright I don't sure what has changed, but it's working partially now. i.e. Only when I reload the conf, xml file is parsed, but when I add a new xml file to folder, it returns empty array again...

Comment: @wizard try to update regex pattern to `pattern => "^<\?xml version"`, Also keep the xml file as its don't wary about `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

My XML files were encoded with
UTF-8 BOM instead of UTF-8. Problem solved!