# What file should sincedb_path be in Logstash? Any example?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Upon research on XML plugin of Logstash, I found [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365566/logstash-xml-parse-failed). When I run this config, there is an exception  `Error: No such file or directory -/dev/null` at `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"`. From the [enter link description here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html), it says

> Path of the sincedb database file (keeps track of the current position
> of monitored log files) that will be written to disk. The default will
> write sincedb files to <path.data>/plugins/inputs/file NOTE: it must
> be a file path and not a directory path

which I still don't understand. My question is what is the file path for `sincedb_path` should be let's say I am running it in Window 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running on Windows and you do not want the in-memory sincedb to be persisted across restarts then you can set sincedb_path to "NUL", which is the Windows equivalent of UNIX's "/dev/null".

Comment: Thanks. No more error now. But, there is no output too. I have created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65174812/unable-to-ingest-xml-file-into-elastic-search-using-logstash-xml-filter

Answer (score 1):

This is a file where the state of the *logstash* is saved.

For example you have a file with 10 lines. We started *logstash* with this file in input configuration, and the process read 8 first line, and for some reason the process is stopped.

When you relaunch *logstash*, it read the *sincedb_path* to know where is the last read of the file targeted by the input configuration. So the process restart the reading step at the last line. Is it the "state" of the *logstash* for this input.

If the value of the  *sincedb_path* is "/dev/null" this means "stateless" for this input file. So for each relaucnh of the *logstash* process, this one restart reading the input file.